# An issue causes the results can not be seen in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, simulation, simulink

By running my simulation in matlab simulink, it takes a long time an remains in the state of processing and doesn't conclude. simulink shows a massage that it suggests to run the below command:

[image]

by entering this command, the above problem remains and just in the length of the time that has been shown beside of processig status, the results in the *Scope* block can be seen that is a very short time. How can fix this problem?

[image]

The massage is:

[image]

and I can see results when duration of simulation running is T=0.222.

Comment: You need to give more details, we have not enough information to help you there. Plus, instead of printing screen, please copy the error messages so we can get documentation without re-copying by hand. MaxConsecutiveZcsMsg is relative to the time-step solver in simulink. If your simulation is still very long disabling it, maybe your system is too complex for the system you are running it on?

Comment: @BenjaminBarrois, the massage has been attached.

Comment: Why did you replace 'untitled' by 'UAVv3'? Your project seems to be named 'untitled'. Try the exact command returned by the error before running your simulation again.

Comment: @BenjaminBarrois, because of entering command of above in project "UAVv3" it doesn;t appera again. just for showing the error massage, I build another file with name  'untitled'.

Comment: @BenjaminBarrois, I don't understan " Try the exact command returned by the error before running your simulation again." correctly?

Comment: Then if it does not appear again I guess the problem is somewhere else. But based on the information you gave I can't tell more.

Comment: Executing the command that you have done doesn't eliminate the problem - as per the text you have shown, it simply stops the message being displayed.  Also as per that message, the first thing to try is to turn off zero crossing detection for the problematic block `untitled\sign`.  Open the `untitled\sign` block and uncheck the zero crossing detection option.  Basically you have a noisy signal (centered about 0) feeding into that block, and that *chatter* is causing the model to run very very slowly or not at all.

Comment: @PhilGoddard, Thanks a lot, your solution is working.